# pandas filtering rows by group value

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Here is the data that I'm practicing with

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mwaskom/seaborn-data/master/tips.csv")
```

I want to filter individual rows by a grouped valued. I know I can do the following to filter groups

```
df.groupby("day").filter(lambda x: x['total_bill'].mean() > 20).day.unique()
```

Which finds which days have an average bill greater than $20. This works because groupby.filter takes a function to apply to each subframe that should return True or False. However, what if I want to find every meal (row) whose value for total_bill is greater than that day's total_bill. Eg if a row has `total_bill` of `22` and was on Sunday, then it should be kept because Sunday's `total_bill` average was `21.41`.

This is my attempt:

```
df.groupby('day').apply(lambda x: x['total_bill'] > x['total_bill'].mean())
```

However, this yields something that looks like this (first few rows)

```
day    
Fri  90     True
     91     True
     92    False
     93    False
     94     True
Name: total_bill, dtype: bool
```

This is not in the same order as the dataframe so I can't just take the boolean column and use it to index the data.

So now I do the following:

```
grouped = (df
           .groupby('day')
           .apply(lambda x: x['total_bill'] > x['total_bill'].mean())
           .reset_index())

index_bill = (grouped
             .loc[grouped.total_bill == True, 'level_1'].values)
df.loc[index_bill]
```

Which gives me the desired result... there has to be an easier way, right? Please let me know if there is a proper way to do this. If not, is there at least a way I can combine the two steps into one? I can do the groupby, but am not sure how to get the values without storing the grouped object as a variable and then referencing it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way I think to do is to use boolean indexing with `groupby` and `transfrom`.  First you group by day to find mean for that day, then use transform to apply that mean to each row, next compare that mean to the actual total_billed on that day, then use that boolean series to filter your dataframe with boolean indexing.

```
df[df.groupby('day')['total_bill'].transform('mean') < df['total_bill']]
```

Output:

```
     total_bill   tip     sex smoker   day    time  size
3         23.68  3.31    Male     No   Sun  Dinner     2
4         24.59  3.61  Female     No   Sun  Dinner     4
5         25.29  4.71    Male     No   Sun  Dinner     4
7         26.88  3.12    Male     No   Sun  Dinner     4
11        35.26  5.00  Female     No   Sun  Dinner     4
15        21.58  3.92    Male     No   Sun  Dinner     2
19        20.65  3.35    Male     No   Sat  Dinner     3
23        39.42  7.58    Male     No   Sat  Dinner     4
28        21.70  4.30    Male     No   Sat  Dinner     2
33        20.69  2.45  Female     No   Sat  Dinner     4
35        24.06  3.60    Male     No   Sat  Dinner     3
39        31.27  5.00    Male     No   Sat  Dinner     3
44        30.40  5.60    Male     No   Sun  Dinner     4
46        22.23  5.00    Male     No   Sun  Dinner     2
47        32.40  6.00    Male     No   Sun  Dinner     4
48        28.55  2.05    Male     No   Sun  Dinner     3
52        34.81  5.20  Female     No   Sun  Dinner     4
54        25.56  4.34    Male     No   Sun  Dinner     4
56        38.01  3.00    Male    Yes   Sat  Dinner     4
57        26.41  1.50  Female     No   Sat  Dinner     2
59        48.27  6.73    Male     No   Sat  Dinner     4
72        26.86  3.14  Female    Yes   Sat  Dinner     2
73        25.28  5.00  Female    Yes   Sat  Dinner     2
77        27.20  4.00    Male     No  Thur   Lunch     4
78        22.76  3.00    Male     No  Thur   Lunch     2
80        19.44  3.00    Male    Yes  Thur   Lunch     2
83        32.68  5.00    Male    Yes  Thur   Lunch     2
85        34.83  5.17  Female     No  Thur   Lunch     4
87        18.28  4.00    Male     No  Thur   Lunch     2
88        24.71  5.85    Male     No  Thur   Lunch     2
..          ...   ...     ...    ...   ...     ...   ...
180       34.65  3.68    Male    Yes   Sun  Dinner     4
181       23.33  5.65    Male    Yes   Sun  Dinner     2
182       45.35  3.50    Male    Yes   Sun  Dinner     3
183       23.17  6.50    Male    Yes   Sun  Dinner     4
184       40.55  3.00    Male    Yes   Sun  Dinner     2
187       30.46  2.00    Male    Yes   Sun  Dinner     5
189       23.10  4.00    Male    Yes   Sun  Dinner     3
191       19.81  4.19  Female    Yes  Thur   Lunch     2
192       28.44  2.56    Male    Yes  Thur   Lunch     2
197       43.11  5.00  Female    Yes  Thur   Lunch     4
200       18.71  4.00    Male    Yes  Thur   Lunch     3
204       20.53  4.00    Male    Yes  Thur   Lunch     4
206       26.59  3.41    Male    Yes   Sat  Dinner     3
207       38.73  3.00    Male    Yes   Sat  Dinner     4
208       24.27  2.03    Male    Yes   Sat  Dinner     2
210       30.06  2.00    Male    Yes   Sat  Dinner     3
211       25.89  5.16    Male    Yes   Sat  Dinner     4
212       48.33  9.00    Male     No   Sat  Dinner     4
214       28.17  6.50  Female    Yes   Sat  Dinner     3
216       28.15  3.00    Male    Yes   Sat  Dinner     5
219       30.14  3.09  Female    Yes   Sat  Dinner     4
227       20.45  3.00    Male     No   Sat  Dinner     4
229       22.12  2.88  Female    Yes   Sat  Dinner     2
230       24.01  2.00    Male    Yes   Sat  Dinner     4
237       32.83  1.17    Male    Yes   Sat  Dinner     2
238       35.83  4.67  Female     No   Sat  Dinner     3
239       29.03  5.92    Male     No   Sat  Dinner     3
240       27.18  2.00  Female    Yes   Sat  Dinner     2
241       22.67  2.00    Male    Yes   Sat  Dinner     2
243       18.78  3.00  Female     No  Thur  Dinner     2

[97 rows x 7 columns]
```

Comment: Great, thanks. So it seems  the general guideline is 'create a column of the values to filter by then use boolean indexing' like your example instead of 'get the indices that satisfy the filter condition' like in my example. So if I wanted to group by day, then get all rows that have are in the highest 10 ranking, I could do `df[df.groupby('day')['total_bill'].rank(ascending=False) < 10]`. This is much better, thanks again!

Comment: @Yes, this from my experience is better preforming that using groupby filter.

Answer (score 1):

For same output need [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for return same `Series` of `mean` per group, then filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and last add [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
a=df[df['total_bill'] > df.groupby('day')['total_bill'].transform('mean')].sort_values('day')
print (a.head(20))
     total_bill   tip     sex smoker  day    time  size
90        28.97  3.00    Male    Yes  Fri  Dinner     2
91        22.49  3.50    Male     No  Fri  Dinner     2
94        22.75  3.25  Female     No  Fri  Dinner     2
95        40.17  4.73    Male    Yes  Fri  Dinner     4
96        27.28  4.00    Male    Yes  Fri  Dinner     2
98        21.01  3.00    Male    Yes  Fri  Dinner     2
102       44.30  2.50  Female    Yes  Sat  Dinner     3
206       26.59  3.41    Male    Yes  Sat  Dinner     3
229       22.12  2.88  Female    Yes  Sat  Dinner     2
227       20.45  3.00    Male     No  Sat  Dinner     4
219       30.14  3.09  Female    Yes  Sat  Dinner     4
237       32.83  1.17    Male    Yes  Sat  Dinner     2
103       22.42  3.48  Female    Yes  Sat  Dinner     2
106       20.49  4.06    Male    Yes  Sat  Dinner     2
107       25.21  4.29    Male    Yes  Sat  Dinner     2
216       28.15  3.00    Male    Yes  Sat  Dinner     5
214       28.17  6.50  Female    Yes  Sat  Dinner     3
241       22.67  2.00    Male    Yes  Sat  Dinner     2
212       48.33  9.00    Male     No  Sat  Dinner     4
211       25.89  5.16    Male    Yes  Sat  Dinner     4
```

EDIT:

For correct ordering by `day`s is possible use [`ordered categorical`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html):

```
cats = ['Mon','Tue','Wed','Thur','Fri','Sat','Sun']
df['day'] = pd.Categorical(df['day'], categories=cats, ordered=True)
means = df.groupby('day')['total_bill'].transform('mean')
df1 = df[df['total_bill'] > means].sort_values('day')
print (df1.head(20))
     total_bill   tip     sex smoker   day   time  size
129       22.82  2.18    Male     No  Thur  Lunch     3
80        19.44  3.00    Male    Yes  Thur  Lunch     2
83        32.68  5.00    Male    Yes  Thur  Lunch     2
85        34.83  5.17  Female     No  Thur  Lunch     4
87        18.28  4.00    Male     No  Thur  Lunch     2
88        24.71  5.85    Male     No  Thur  Lunch     2
89        21.16  3.00    Male     No  Thur  Lunch     2
119       24.08  2.92  Female     No  Thur  Lunch     4
125       29.80  4.20  Female     No  Thur  Lunch     6
130       19.08  1.50    Male     No  Thur  Lunch     2
78        22.76  3.00    Male     No  Thur  Lunch     2
131       20.27  2.83  Female     No  Thur  Lunch     2
141       34.30  6.70    Male     No  Thur  Lunch     6
142       41.19  5.00    Male     No  Thur  Lunch     5
143       27.05  5.00  Female     No  Thur  Lunch     6
146       18.64  1.36  Female     No  Thur  Lunch     3
191       19.81  4.19  Female    Yes  Thur  Lunch     2
192       28.44  2.56    Male    Yes  Thur  Lunch     2
197       43.11  5.00  Female    Yes  Thur  Lunch     4
200       18.71  4.00    Male    Yes  Thur  Lunch     3
```

Comment: Thank you for this, and going the extra step of showing `ordered categorical`. I have marked the other answer as the solution only because the direct answer to my question is the same as yours, they just answered first